# ClickHouse: Output inserted rows of INSERT INTO ... SELECT

Tags: sql, clickhouse

When executing a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement that directly inserts the resulting rows of the `SELECT` query, is there any way to output these newly inserted rows?

Some research shows that for example SQL Server has an `OUTPUT` clause for `INSERT` to achieve this, but I couldn't find anything similar with ClickHouse.

The intention is to avoid having to send two separate queries via our client application.

Comment: There is no such feature

Comment: Thank you @DennyCrane for your quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

As partial solution, you can try to add `task_id LowCardinality(String)` into your destination table
after it, generate `task_id` value on your application side and use two separate queries

```sql
INSERT INTO ... SELECT 'xxx' AS task_id ...;
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE task_id=?
```

Comment: Good idea! Have to check if it performs better than `SELECT` then `INSERT` values again for our use case.